# How to avoid duplication of add_header directives in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

The documentation says this:

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

My problem is that I have several `location` blocks that I want to cache, like this one:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

location ~ ^/img/(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

But that will make me lose all the headers declared outside of the block. So apparently the only way is duplicating those headers on every `location` block, eg:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

location ~ ^/img/(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
}
```

Doesn't seem right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) in each location in include shared headers (this must be duplicated but only needs to be updated in the included config not each block individually).

Answer (score 1):

That's how nginx `add_header` works.

Another solution is to use the unofficial nginx module [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme) instead. It allows setting headers with the expected behavior, among other features. It's not for everyone, because it's not distributed with nginx (although it is available in Debian/Ubuntu via the nginx-extras package), and it also requires updating existing configurations.